# Integrating the Apphud SDK with iOS

Tags: swift

I'm trying to integrate the [Apphud SDK](https://github.com/apphud/ApphudSDK). I want to purchase a specific product with product id `sub_30`. I'm using the iOS SDK.

How can I query for a specific product instead of all products? For example, I want to query for a specific product with id `sub_30`, and pass it to the purchase function below? What function can I use to do that?

```swift
let result = await Apphud.purchase(product)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch products like below,

```
let products = try await Apphud.fetchProducts()
```

Then You can filtered your required product detail based on with product_id like below,

```
let resultedProducts = products.filter({$0.id == "sub_30"})
debugPrint("products successfully fetched: \(resultedProducts.first)")
```